# Retrieving Weekend Data Rows Only in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

How to query rows in a table where the created_date column value in the table falls on a weekend date ONLY, i.e. Saturday/Sunday using Oracle SQL..

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE  TO_CHAR (created_date, 'DY') IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
```

Answer (score 2):

@Joe Stefanelli This is not absolutely correct, since the abbreviations returned are NLS-sensitive: the language in which month and day names and abbreviations are returned use the default date language for your session.

If you compare to-char result to literals in English (`IN ('SAT', 'SUN')`), it's better to precisely indicate it with `nlsparams` parameter, so the resulting query will look like this:

```
SELECT *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE  TO_CHAR (created_date, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE to_char(created_date, 'D') >= 6
```

To improve the performance you could create function based index `to_char(created_date, 'D')`

Comment: -1 not locale-safe; on my system, Saturday is 7 and Sunday is 1.

Comment: depends on the setting of NLS_TERRITORY.